# Stack Overflow Jobs - Wrong link in "Learn more about 'company'"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

`Learn more about {..}` button brings you to the preview page of the company.

[image]

Comment: It should be enough to take out the query string from URL if I'm not the publisher of the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to report this! I've uploaded a fix and <strike>it should be live in a matter of hours</strike> it's live now